# How to disable "Google Drive for desktop is coming soon" dialog box when system starts up?

Tags: windows-10, dialog

How to disable the below dialog box which pops up every time my system starts.

[image: google Drive for desktop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialogue box appears because Google has announced the end of the Google Backup&Sync tool. Its functionalities are now integrated into the new Google Drive Desktop application, so you need to deinstall the old one and install and set up the new application. It can be downloaded [here](https://dl.google.com/drive-file-stream/GoogleDriveSetup.exe). After deinstalling, the annoying popup should be gone, and all new updates are automatically added by an update service integrated into the new Google Drive for desktop.